# Inserting records to Netezza with py spark JDBC API creating a lot of queries

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I recently started working with Spark and came across a situation where I read in some data, do some calculations, and have a need of inserting all the output records to a netezza table. I am able to read and write data to and from my netezza database, but when I try to insert records to a table from my DataFrame, I see on the Netezza Admin screen that the process creates around 100+ insert queries, my data set can vary from 4M to 15M. Below is how I am achieving this:

my `DataFrame` is `tableDF`

```
jprop = JavaClass("java.util.Properties", sc._gateway._gateway_client)()
for k in properties:
     jprop.setProperty(k, properties[k])

sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils.saveTable(tableDF._jdf,netezzaServerURL,tableName,jprop)
```

Can anyone help me in identifying how I can limit the number of connections/insert queries when I try to insert records? Is there a configuration in the `JDBC` connection that I need to set? DataFrame paritionBy, maybe?

Comment: Do you use `coalesce(X)` on dataframe to limit partitions number before `saveTable`?

Comment: I have not used that yet. I can give it a try

Comment: I need some help in writing to netezza DB using Spark => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135791/feasibility-of-hive-to-netezza-data-export-using-spark?noredirect=1#comment71475527_42135791