# Feasibility of Hive to Netezza data export using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, netezza, apache-spark-dataset

This mail is to discuss on a use case, on which my team is working.
It's to export metadata and data from a HIVE server to RDBMS.

On doing that, export to MySQL and ORACLE is working good, but export to

Netezza is failing with error message:

```
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: json at RdbmsSandboxExecution.java:80, took 0.433405 s
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) in 143 ms on localhost (1/1)
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.createJDBCTable(DataFrame.scala:1767)
        at com.zaloni.mica.datatype.conversion.RdbmsSandboxExecution.main(RdbmsSandboxExecution.java:81)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static/sql,null}
17/02/09 16:03:07 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/SQL1/execution/json,null}
```

We are using DataFrame.createJDBCTable.

The spark-submit command which we are using is :

```
spark-submit --class <java_class_with_export_logic> --master local --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/absolute-path/nzjdbc3.jar --jars /absolute-path/nzjdbc3.jar /absolute-path/<application-jar <JDBC_URL>
```

Comment: You spark sumit command should be something like:
spark-submit --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/absolute-path/nzjdbc3.jar --jars /absolute-path/nzjdbc3.jar --class <name of the class containing your code>

Comment: Whats the difference between "local[*]" and "local" ? "local" is working fine for MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: The problem is not with the local[*] but with the sequence of the options in spark-submit .I have faced the same problem long before and moving --class option at the end solved my problem hence suggested

Comment: Pushing --class option to the end, throw'd this error =>
Error: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output

Comment: Which spark version ? I am using 1.6.1

Comment: After --class option you have to specify the name of the class that contains your driver code.Can you paste the actual command you are executing?

Comment: spark-submit --master local --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/nzjdbc3.jar --jars /path/nzjdbc3.jar /path/provisioning.jar 3.1 "jdbc:netezza://<IP-Address>:5480/SPIKEPROV;user=user;password=password" http://192.168.2.163:9090 admin admin 50% true  --class com.datatype.conversion.RdbmsSandboxExecution

Comment: Can you execute it as follows:
spark-submit --master local --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/nzjdbc3.jar --jars /path/nzjdbc3.jar /path/provisioning.jar 3.1  --class com.zaloni.mica.datatype.conversion.RdbmsSandboxExecution "jdbc:netezza://<IP-Address>:5480/SPIKEPROV;user=user;passwo‌​rd=password" 192.168.2.163:9090 admin admin 50% true

Comment: You meant, I shouldn't provide "/path/provisioning.jar 3.1" ??

Comment: Got a solution to this. Thanks to everyone, who all have helped me to go to the solution.

Comment: Please post your solution as a Answer so that it will help others searching for the same problem

Comment: Spark-1.6 didn't had support for Netezza. So, created a custom NetezzaDialect class, by extending JdbcDialect class, and mapped the Data Types.